# How to set onItemclick in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to call a swipeview when the image from my fragment gridview is clicked but I am not able to se it properly .earlier I have connected the my gridview with the swipe view in mainactivity but here I am getting error

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    GridView gridView=(GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(view.getContext()));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Pic"+(position)+"Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent= new Intent(view.getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pic",position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

I am getting error in getbaseContext and I may be wrong in setting MyAdapter(view.getContext() so plz help in solving the error

Comment: Use _getActivity()_ instead of _getBaseContext()_

Comment: thx @cricket_007 2nd time u helped me

Comment: I just like cleaning up questions while I'm on my phone. I figure I'm helping bump questions to the front page

Comment: hehe I will also help U soon in future its my 3rd month in android development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `getActivity()` instead of `view.getcontext()` and for swipe view i think u can add that functionality by adding left to right animation. Actually i dont understand what do u mean by calling  swipeview when image is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    GridView gridView=(GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(view.getContext()));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Pic"+(position)+"Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent= new Intent(getContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("pic",position);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```